# Maven JMS libraries are gone?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I noticed this yesterday that my maven java project is missing JMS 1.1, JMX tools 1.2.1, and JMX RI 1.2.1 by unfold the Maven dependencies in Java build path, so I could not build my project. I also checked maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms/1.1 and the file shows 404 not found.

Does anyone know what is happening about Maven?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look in MavenCentral

http://search.maven.org

you will still find it.

(mvnrepository is *not* MavenCentral)

Comment: mvnrepository do download from Maven central, isn't it? Yes it is still findable, but based on Eclipse's behavior and mvnrepository, that lib file got something very wrong.

Comment: No, mvnrepository is just a kind of search engine for artifacts, I would not use it in my POM.